# Column level permissions in sharepoint 2010 using Server Object Model

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am new to sharepoint.i have created a list with some columns from a console application using Server OM and c#.My requirement is when a perticular user logs in i want to hide some columns.like this i want to customize the columns that a perticular user can see.
 I have checked for permissions but there are no concept like "Column level permissions".
I have tried with the "hidden" property of column.like

`SPField f = list.Fields["Abc"]` and `f.Hidden = true`.

but doesnt work for me as i want to hide and show columns depending upon the current user.
can anybody help me tosolve this?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this feature: http://permissionmanagement.codeplex.com/ The solution allow you to create a column level permission. In your case, you assign permission to users defined in the column item.
Also, you can try the other product like [column permission](http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission.html)